# How to operate on list of data frame in one instruction

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

For example:
I have four pandas Dateframe `df1,df2,df3,df4`. And my work process to these 4 dataframe are the same?
How to define `i =(1,2,3,4) link with "df"`

So, I don't have to change `"df1"-> "df2/3/4"` so many time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you have numbered variable names, think about using a list instead. For example:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
for df in dfs:
    ....
```

Moreover, it might behoove you to refactor the code defining `df1`, `df2`, `df3` and `df4` so as to eliminate those variables and define the list `dfs` alone. Then, instead of `df2`, for instance, you would just refer to `dfs[1]`. Instead of

```
df1 = ...
df2 = ...
df3 = ...
df4 = ...
```

you would use something like

```
dfs = []
for i in range(4):
    dfs.append(...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! @unutbu